# Keras custom layer using argmax kills gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After implementing a custom layer in Keras and using it in my network, I realized that all previous layers are not updated during training anymore. In fact, analyzing the *tensorboard distributions* of the weights and gradients computed for my network, the gradients for all layers preceding the custom layer are zero.

The layer I am trying to implement performs the following:

**Goal:**
Given a tensor of size `B x H x W x D`, with `D=1`, add two new channels of size `H x W` to each sample of the batch (the values of these channels are given as a constant input, so they are not learned or dynamic). For the resulting tensor of shape `B x H x W x 3`, compute the *argmax* on the first channel sample-wise (i.e. over the 2 dimensional image) and apply the resulting indices on the second and third channel.

**Shapes:**
Given `B x H x W x D = (B x 8 x 8 x 1)`, the layer outputs a tensor of shape `B x 2 x 1` with an intermediate representation of size `B x H x W x 3`.

**Numerical example:**
Let's assume `B = 1`, `H = W = 2`, and let the input tensor have the following values:

```
input[0, :, :, 0] = [[0.1, 0.2],
                     [0.3, 0.4]]
```

Adding the new channels:

```
input[0, :, :, 0] = [[0.1, 0.2],
                     [0.3, 0.4]]

input[0, :, :, 1] = [[a, b],
                     [c, d]]

input[0, :, :, 2] = [[e, f],
                     [g, h]]
```

The filter computes the *argmax* on the first channel, and returns the corresponding elements of the second and third channel:

```
indices = argmax(input[0, :, :, 0]) = [1, 1]
input[0,indices[0], indices[1], 1] = [d]
input[0,indices[0], indices[1], 1] = [h]

Layer(input) = [
                 [[d], [h]]
               ]
```

Here I attach the code I wrote to implement the filter's logic:

```
class CustomGlobalMaxPooling(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Layer computing the argmax in the first channel of each sample in the input
        tensor and returning the values associated to the second and third channel.
        """

        super(CustomGlobalMaxPooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 4, "Only 4 dimensional input supported (B, H, W, D)"
        assert input_shape[-1] == 1, "Only supports one channels. Given shape: {}".format(input_shape)
        super(CustomGlobalMaxPooling, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
        r = tf.cast(tf.range(batch_size), tf.int64)

        img_h = tf.shape(x)[1]
        img_w = tf.shape(x)[2]

        ## HERE WE ADD THE NEW CHANNELS ON EACH SAMPLE (code omitted) ##
        x = add_channels(x)

        flattened_values = tf.reshape(x[:, :, :, 0], (batch_size, img_h * img_w))
        flattened_1 = tf.reshape(x[:, :, :, 1], (batch_size, img_h * img_w))
        flattened_2 = tf.reshape(x[:, :, :, 2], (batch_size, img_h * img_w))

        argmax = tf.argmax(flattened_values, axis=1)
        argmax = tf.transpose(tf.stack([r, argmax]), [1, 0])

        max_1 = tf.gather_nd(flattened_1, argmax)
        max_2 = tf.gather_nd(flattened_2, argmax)

        max_1 = tf.expand_dims(max_1, -1)
        max_2 = tf.expand_dims(max_2, -1)

        return tf.transpose(tf.stack((max_1, max_2)), [1, 0, 2])

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        batch_size = input_shape[0]
        return (batch_size, 2, 1)
```

I guess that by performing the armgax on one channel and applying the indices on new channels, my network is not differentiable anymore, so no gradients can propagate.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: The only way is to return values or operations on values from the original input (not from the constant inputs).